# web2py: Limit the values in a select in a CRUD form

Tags: web2py

I have these tables:

```
db.define_table('category',
Field('name')
)

db.define_table('field',
Field('name')
Field('category', db.category)
)

db.define_table('settings',    #id is the workspace id
Field('size', type="integer"),
Field('field', db.field),
)
```

I want a CRUD form for the settings table for a given category and limit the fields to the fields for the category. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like more of a job for a `SQLFORM.grid`, where you can specify a query for what you want to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i correctly understood your question, but i guess that you will want to use `db().select(db.settings.ALL, limitby=(0, x))` where x would be how many lines you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted like so:

```
db.settings.field.requires = IS_IN_DB(db((db.field.category==cat)), "field.id", "%(name)s" )
```

before creating the crud.update form.